# Symfony (SonataAdmin) - Ajax call controller - migrate javascript in js file twig fail

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a standard Symfony project using SonataAdminBundle.

I had the following javascript in a  balise in the view trainer-edit.html.twig:

```
       $.ajax({
            url: '{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('massEvents', object) }}',
            data: datas,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {
                $('.sonata-ba-form form').removeAttr('data-original');
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
```

To have a better partitioning of the code, i decided to create a file trainer-edit.js and migrate my javascript into it and reference it in my view using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('assets/js/Admin/Trainer/trainer-edit.js') }}"></script>
```

The problem is, that section of the code obviously cannot be resolved in the .js file because it's twig:

```
url: '{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('massEvents', object) }}'
```

So i was wondering two things (i'm new to symfony):

- Is it a good approach to partition your code like so in a symfony (using sonata) environment ? Why or why not ?
- If so, what's the workaround to allow me to map the controller directly in the js ?

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

you could use the FOSJsRoutingBundle. This exposes a router to your js that can be used to access you symfony routes in your javascript.

See:
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html#router-service